# Rounded DialogFrament

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I  need ViewPager inside  DialogFragment with rounded corners. I try create custom ViewPager. Here my onDraw method:

```
int mArcRadius = 2 * Math.round(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.round_radius));
        Path mCornerPath = new Path();
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mCornerPath.moveTo(0,canvas.getHeight());
        RectF rectLeftCorner = new RectF(0, canvas.getHeight() - mArcRadius, mArcRadius, canvas.getHeight());
        mCornerPath.arcTo(rectLeftCorner, 90, 90);
        RectF rectRightCorner = new RectF(canvas.getWidth() - mArcRadius, canvas.getHeight() - mArcRadius, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        mCornerPath.moveTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        mCornerPath.arcTo(rectRightCorner, 0, 90);
        mCornerPath.close();
        canvas.drawPath(mCornerPath, mPaint);
```

But it not work. ViewPage fragments located above ViewPager. Then i try create custom fragment layout in the same way. It works if I do not slide the fragments.
Otherwise it turns out like this
[image]

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method as i used:

Background Drawable for your dialog to be rounded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item> 
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent_black" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/border_radius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>   
    <item 
        android:left="@dimen/border_width" 
        android:right="@dimen/border_width"  
        android:top="@dimen/border_width"
        android:bottom="@dimen/border_width" >  

        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/border_radius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>    
</layer-list>
```

layout of the dialog as you need in xml(do self).

Java code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_tom, null);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(child);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            alertDialog.show();

alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: i already try set shape as background. it is not work. because viewpager fragments above dialogfragment root layout